# Use another attribute instead of the input value to update total

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

basically the below code creates a order total in the id="total" span depending on which checkbox/radio buttons are selected. The total is changed by the value of the checkbox/radio buttons however i was wondering if there's any other way to change the total without using the inputs value because its needed in the next part of the form. Maybe another input attribute? I'm just not sure how to go about it.

All help will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```html
<form action="cart.php" method="post" name="builder">
<input checked="checked" type="radio" name="term" value="12" onclick='check_value(this, 1)' />
<input type="radio" name="term" value="24" onclick='check_value(this, 2)' />
<input type="radio" name="term" value="36" onclick='check_value(this, 3)' />

<input type="checkbox" name="cid[]"  value="2" onclick='check_value(this, "")' />
<input type="checkbox" name="cid[]"  value="3" onclick='check_value(this, "")' />
<input type="checkbox" name="cid[]"  value="4" onclick='check_value(this, "")' />

Total Order: $<span id="total">36</span>
</form>
```

```js
function check_value(curElem, id) {
            // calculate Total
            var total = 0;
            var controls = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for (var i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) {
                if ((controls[i].type === 'radio' || controls[i].type === 'checkbox') && controls[i].checked) {
                    total = total + parseFloat(controls[i].value);
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
            //alert("Total: " + total);
        }
```

Comment: You can always use `data-` attribute to attach custom data to elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you really want to use another attribute, use it

use an attribute of your choice, say `nval`  and access it as `controls[i].getAttribute("nval")`

otherwise,

you can create plenty of `hidden input fields` in the page, for each checkbox to hold your value. and use these hidden fields to compute total.

Comment: I tried you function in chrome 43, and it just worked, but you can getAttribute of 'value' rather than use non-standard attribute. i.e., controls[i].getAttribute('value').

Comment: He wanted to avoid using value, for reason that I don't know yet. So I suggested this answer

Comment: I actually need some more attributes to use like the nval and data attributes suggested. What else can i use? Can i make them up?

Comment: Yes you can,  you can make your own values, as long as your browser supports it.